# How to count the occurrence of two char values in a given String

Tags: java, string, int

```
public int count_two_chars(String s, char c, char d){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
       if(s.charAt(i) == c + d){
           counter = counter + 1;
       }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I need to define this method so that it returns as an int, the number of times either char c or char d is present in String s.

Only methods able to be called on String s are charAt(int) and length.

I would really like some help with this, not just the code because what does that do for me as a new programmer?

Comment: Why are you trying to add two `char`s? Java will let you do it, but it's like trying to figure out the sum of Monday and Wednesday. Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: Asking for a rephrase: Are you trying to count the number of occurrences of `c` and `d` in `s`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do there. (c + d)? Maybe you mean C or D, not C + D?

Comment: Say I have test where s is "abcdef", and i the method to count how many  a's and b's are in that string. So c is 'a' and d is 'b'. I would want the out put to be '2'. Because there is 1 'a' and 1 'b'.

It's also just an exercise for me to practice simple methods. Also I'm new at this so sorry if it's unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to count the number of occurances of either char c or char d. This is not achieved by adding them together, this results in an entirely different char altogether.

You nearly had it correct actually, just change your if condition:

```
if(s.charAt(i) == c || s.charAt(i) == d)
```

Also, note the `||` operator to denote OR.

Comment: Thanks! This is it! Also thanks for specifying that || means OR!